# adding second to timer iOS game sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nstimer

I am trying to add a few seconds to countdown timer each time when enemy and player node     contacts.
     Also when the player reach to some certain point I want player to pass to another level. I am         sending part of the code . Could anybody help me to solve this problem. By the way because I am new to programming my code is a little hard to read . Sorry for that.
Thanks

```
        -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime{

   if (startGamePlay){
    startTime = currentTime;
    startGamePlay = NO;
}

 countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime-startTime);

 if(countDownInt > 0 ){  //if counting down to 0 show counter
    countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countDownInt];
}


  else if (countDownInt == 0){
        countDown.text =@"0";
        Level2 *level2  = [Level2 sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.5];
        [self.view presentScene:level2  transition:transition];
    }
}



    - (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
} else {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}


if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryBrick && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryShark ) {
    NSLog(@"BRICK");

  [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];

} else if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryWaterBall && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryShark ) {
    NSLog(@"BALL");
    countDownInt = [countDown.text intValue];
    [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
    [self addPoints:PointsPerHit];

   if (![ self childNodeWithName:@"WATERBALLTL"]) {
        [self addWaterBallTopLeft];
    }
    if (![ self childNodeWithName:@"WATERBALLTR"]) {
        [self addWaterBallTopRight];
    }
    if (![ self childNodeWithName:@"WATERBALLBL"]) {
        [self addWaterBallBottomLeft];
    }
    if (![ self childNodeWithName:@"WATERBALLBR"]) {
        [self addWaterBallBottomRight];
    }
 }
  NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.children count]);
}





 #import "HudNode.h"

  @implementation HudNode

 {
    SKLabelNode *countDown;
    BOOL startGamePlay;
    NSTimeInterval startTime;
 }

  + (instancetype) hudAtPosition:(CGPoint)position inFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  HudNode *hud = [self node];
  hud.position = position;
  hud.zPosition = 10;
  hud.name = @"HUD";



   SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold"];
     scoreLabel.name = @"Score";
    scoreLabel.text = @"0";
scoreLabel.fontSize = 24;
scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width-20, -10);
scoreLabel.zPosition = 12;
[hud addChild:scoreLabel];
        SKLabelNode *countDown = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Futura-Medium"];
        countDown.fontSize = 50;
        countDown.position = CGPointMake(30, -10);
        countDown.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter; //good for     positioning with other sprites
        countDown.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor ];
        countDown.name = @"countDown";
        countDown.zPosition = 100;
        [hud addChild:countDown];


return  hud;
 }

   - (void) addPoints:(NSInteger)points {
self.score += points;

SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = (SKLabelNode *) [self childNodeWithName:@"Score"];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%li", (long)self.score];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean flag that the update method checks to see if it should add seconds.

Add the following variable and set `self.addSeconds = NO;` initially:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL addSeconds;
```

Set `self.addSeconds =YES;` in the method where your player hits your enemy:

Add the following to the very beginning of the Update:

```
if(self.addSeconds == YES)
{
    CountDownInt+=  5 //Change this to add as many seconds as you want
    self.addSeconds=NO;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: meisenman Thank you, It kind of worked. The problem is now when the contact happens first time it adds seconds to the text but it does not change the actual timer. for example: Lets say it counts down from 10 and we are adding 5 seconds each time.If contact happens when the timer at 8 it will change the text to 13 but when the text shows the last 6th second, it will drop from 6 to 0 suddenly and timer will end. And the other problem it just add seconds on the first contact . when I hit the enemy second or third time it does not add time anymore.Do you have any idea.

Comment: You are redefining your CountDownInt each time the update runs.  Use the same code but instead replace `CountDownInt+=  5` with `StartTime+=5`